# Scraping of protected email

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need to scrape emails from the website.
It's visible in a browser but when I try to scrape it with requests\BeautifulSoup I get this: "[email protected]"

I can do this with Selenium but it will take more time and I would like to know is it possible to scrape these emails with requests\BeautifulSoup? Maybe it's needed to use some libraries for working with js.

The email tag:

```
<span id="signature_email"><a class="__cf_email__" href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection" data-cfemail="30425f5e70584346515c5c531e535f5d">[email&#160;protected]</a><script data-cfhash='f9e31' type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */!function(t,e,r,n,c,a,p){try{t=document.currentScript||function(){for(t=document.getElementsByTagName('script'),e=t.length;e--;)if(t[e].getAttribute('data-cfhash'))return t[e]}();if(t&&(c=t.previousSibling)){p=t.parentNode;if(a=c.getAttribute('data-cfemail')){for(e='',r='0x'+a.substr(0,2)|0,n=2;a.length-n;n+=2)e+='%'+('0'+('0x'+a.substr(n,2)^r).toString(16)).slice(-2);p.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(decodeURIComponent(e)),c)}p.removeChild(t)}}catch(u){}}()/* ]]> */</script></span></span> <span class="separator">|</span>
```

Comment: Are these emails from a mailing list ? Can't you simply fetch them from the mailing list ?

Comment: No, emails are on web-pages.

Comment: Can you show the code where you make the request? Did you include a user agent? also a link to the page would be helpful so we can see how the email gets displayed

Comment: BeautifulSoup does not evaluate javascript. So I think you have to stick with Selenium...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the CF tag, in your supplied html, I assume you are scraping a cloudflare site. They offer a feature to obfuscate emails listed ([see here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170016-What-is-Email-Address-Obfuscation-)) which encrypts the addresses in the HTML and using JavaScript decrypts them. Hence, using selenium you'll see email-addresses but using requests you won't.

Since the decryption method can be easily taken from the JavaScript, you can write your own decryption method in Python.

In JavaScript,

```
(function () {
    try {
        var s, a, i, j, r, c, l = document.getElementById("__cf_email__");
        a = l.className;
        if (a) {
            s = '';
            r = parseInt(a.substr(0, 2), 16);
            for (j = 2; a.length - j; j += 2) {
                c = parseInt(a.substr(j, 2), 16) ^ r;
                s += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            s = document.createTextNode(s);
            l.parentNode.replaceChild(s, l);
        }
    } catch (e) {}
})();
```

In Python,

```
def decodeEmail(e):
    de = ""
    k = int(e[:2], 16)

    for i in range(2, len(e)-1, 2):
        de += chr(int(e[i:i+2], 16)^k)

    return de
```

Comment: Fantastic! sowa, thank you very much! It works perfectly.

Comment: I think maybe this answer is outdated, it did not work for me on Apr 23, 2023. The answer by @Rohit Dhiman below did.

Answer (score 14):

Code In all Languages is [here](https://usamaejaz.com/cloudflare-email-decoding/):

**Javascript**

```
function cfDecodeEmail(encodedString) {
    var email = "", r = parseInt(encodedString.substr(0, 2), 16), n, i;
    for (n = 2; encodedString.length - n; n += 2){
        i = parseInt(encodedString.substr(n, 2), 16) ^ r;
        email += String.fromCharCode(i);
    }
    return email;
}

console.log(cfDecodeEmail("543931142127353935313e352e7a373b39")); // usage
```

**Python**

```
def cfDecodeEmail(encodedString):
    r = int(encodedString[:2],16)
    email = ''.join([chr(int(encodedString[i:i+2], 16) ^ r) for i in range(2, len(encodedString), 2)])
    return email

print cfDecodeEmail('543931142127353935313e352e7a373b39') # usage
```

**PHP**

```
function cfDecodeEmail($encodedString){
  $k = hexdec(substr($encodedString,0,2));
  for($i=2,$email='';$i<strlen($encodedString)-1;$i+=2){
    $email.=chr(hexdec(substr($encodedString,$i,2))^$k);
  }
  return $email;
}

echo cfDecodeEmail('543931142127353935313e352e7a373b39'); // usage
```

**GO**

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "strconv"
)

func cf(a string) (s string) {
    var e bytes.Buffer
    r, _ := strconv.ParseInt(a[0:2], 16, 0)
    for n := 4; n < len(a)+2; n += 2 {
        i, _ := strconv.ParseInt(a[n-2:n], 16, 0)
        e.WriteString(string(i ^ r))
    }
    return e.String()
}

func main() {
    email := cf("543931142127353935313e352e7a373b39") // usage
    print(email)
    print("\n")
}
```

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string cfDecodeEmail(string encodedString);

int main()
{
    cout << cfDecodeEmail("543931142127353935313e352e7a373b39") << endl;
}

string cfDecodeEmail(string encodedString)
{
    string email;
    char xorKey = stoi( encodedString.substr(0, 2), nullptr, 16);
    for( unsigned i = 2; i < encodedString.length(); i += 2)
        email += stoi( encodedString.substr(i, 2), nullptr, 16) ^ xorKey;

    return email;
}
```

**C#**

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static string cfDecodeEmail(string encodedString)
    {
        string email = "";
        int r = Convert.ToInt32(encodedString.Substring(0, 2), 16), n, i;
        for (n = 2; encodedString.Length - n > 0; n += 2)
        {
            i = Convert.ToInt32(encodedString.Substring(n, 2), 16) ^ r;
            char character = (char)i;
            email += Convert.ToString(character);
        }

        return email;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cfDecodeEmail("543931142127353935313e352e7a373b39")); // usage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to above algorithm, I wrote code in Ruby to parse [protected email] with nokogiri

```
def decode_email(e)
  r = Integer(e[0,2], 16)
  (2..e.length - 2).step(2).map do |j|
    c = Integer(e[j,2], 16) ^ r
    c.chr
  end.join('')
end
```