# BeautifulSoup 4 HTML Web Scraping - Find Mailto Links and Export to Spreadsheet

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all email addresses from this index page - http://www.uschess.org/assets/msa_joomla/AffiliateSearch/clubresultsnew.php?st=AL

I modified a python script to define the string, parse content with BS4 and save each unique address to an xls file:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('Emails')
ws.write(0,0,'Emails')

emailList= []
r=0

#add url of the page you want to scrape to urlString
urlString='http://www.uschess.org/assets/msa_joomla/AffiliateSearch/clubresultsnew.php?st=AL'

#function that extracts all emails from a page you provided and stores them in a list
def emailExtractor(urlString):
getH=requests.get(urlString)
h=getH.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(h,'html.parser')
mailtos = soup.select('a[href^=mailto]')
for i in mailtos:
    href=i['href']
    try:
        str1, str2 = href.split(':')
    except ValueError:
        break
    
    emailList.append(str2)
    
   emailExtractor(urlString)
   #adding scraped emails to an excel sheet
   for email in emailList:
   r=r+1
   ws.write(r,0,email)

    wb.save('emails.xls')
```

The xls file exports as expected, but with no email values. If anyone can explain why or how to simplify this solution it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pls check whether my answer satisfies your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the emails are protected. I am adding only the email scraping part. and not adding the excel part since you dont have issues with that. converting email protected to text credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/36913154/7518304

```
emailList= []
r=0

#add url of the page you want to scrape to urlString
urlString='http://www.uschess.org/assets/msa_joomla/AffiliateSearch/clubresultsnew.php?st=AL'
def decodeEmail(e): #https://stackoverflow.com/a/36913154/7518304
    de = ""
    k = int(e[:2], 16)

    for i in range(2, len(e)-1, 2):
        de += chr(int(e[i:i+2], 16)^k)

    return de

#function that extracts all emails from a page you provided and stores them in a list
def emailExtractor(urlString):
    getH=requests.get(urlString)
    h=getH.content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(h,'html.parser')
    mailtos = soup.select('a[href]')
    for i in mailtos:
        href=i['href']
        if "email-protect" in href:
            emailList.append(decodeEmail(href.split("#")[1]))

emailExtractor(urlString)
emailList
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` for this. Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd

urlString = 'http://www.uschess.org/assets/msa_joomla/AffiliateSearch/clubresultsnew.php?st=AL'


# function that extracts all emails from a page you provided and stores them in a list
def emailExtractor(urlString):
   
    emailList = []
    getH = requests.get(urlString)
    h = getH.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(h, 'html.parser')

    mailtos = soup.find_all('a')

    href_lst = []
    for i in mailtos:
        href_lst.append(i['href'])

    for href in href_lst:
        if ':' in href:
            emailList.append(href)
    print(emailList)

    s = pd.Series(emailList)

    s = s.rename('Emails')
    
    s.to_excel('D:\\Emails.xls',index=False)

emailExtractor(urlString)
```

Output:

```
['http://msa.uschess.org/AffDtlMain.php?T6006791', 'https://alabamachess.org', 'http://msa.uschess.org/AffDtlMain.php?A6029262', 'http://www.caesarchess.com/', 'http://msa.uschess.org/AffDtlMain.php?A6045660', 'http://msa.uschess.org/AffDtlMain.php?H6046485', 'http://msa.uschess.org/AffDtlMain.php?A6040580']
```

Excel Sheet Screenshot:

[image]

If you want the links to be output to the excel sheet as `hyperlinks` (you will be redirected to the website once you click the link), then change `emailList.append(href)` to `emailList.append('=HYPERLINK("'+href+'")')`.
And at the same time, you should also change the file extension to `.xlsx`. Only then, you can get the links as hyperlinks.

Output:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: YW! A humble request from my side. Could u upvote my answer and accept it as the best answer?

Comment: If not accept, at least upvote my answer. Coz I have spent a lot of time to find the solution and to frame my answer. Hope u will understand. Thanks!