# scraping protected email in php

Tags: python, php

I have written a php function that decode the protected email based on this answer

> [Scraping of protected email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911296/scraping-of-protected-email)

I took this function

```
def decodeEmail(e):
    de = ""
    k = int(e[:2], 16)

    for i in range(2, len(e)-1, 2):
        de += chr(int(e[i:i+2], 16)^k)

    return de
```

converted to php :

```
function decode($e){
$de= "";
$c = substr($e,0,2);
$k = hexdec($c);

foreach(range(2, strlen($e)-1, 2) as $i => $v){
       $s = substr($e,$i,$i+2);
       $d = hexdec($s);
       $de .= chr($d^$k);
}
return $de;
}
```

the function works almost except the last three characters, sometimes two, sometimes one.
sample :

given value

```
caaba0a3bea28af9fcfabfabaeb9e4a9a5a7
```

it returns

```
ajith@360uads���
```

the correct result should be

```
ajith@360uads.com
```

what did I do wrong in my function ? what did I miss from the original python function ?

Comment: Don’t give us this vague “sometimes this, sometimes that” stuff, but give specific examples of how this fails on what exact input.

Comment: @CBroe updated the question with sample